# boundary conditions with non-constant coefficients in cell centred finite volume method

Tags: numerical-analysis, boundary-conditions, finite-volume, discretization, accuracy

- Suppose am solving the heat conduction equation in 1d with
  Dirichlet boundary conditions. The thermal conductivity $k$ is a non
  constant function.
  So $-(k(x)u'(x))' = f(x)$
- The value of $k$ enters the discretization only through its values at
  the faces of the control volume $k_{i+1/2}, \; k_{i-1/2}$, and not at the cell centres $k_i$.
- But most books and notes available online suggest that we store the
  value of $k$ at cell centres a priori and use it in the computation.

  1. If $k(x)$ has jumps  across the faces, I understand one uses the harmonic average.  What about control volumes near the boundary ? What is the  standard way to approximate $k(x)$ there; harmonic averaging with neighbour is not possible. Can I simply use the cell centre value for these cells ?

I am unable to see how approximating $k(x)$ will eventually affect the order of
accuracy of the method in these  cases.

My question is about accuracy, not exactly the same as [How should non-constant coefficients be treated with finite-volume first order upwind scheme?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7456/how-should-non-constant-coefficients-be-treated-with-finite-volume-first-order-u),

**EDIT**:
When $k(x)$ is smooth, by expanding  the terms $k_{i+1/2}, \; k_{i-1/2}$ in a Taylor's series around $k_i$ in the standard 3 point scheme, I see that using the cell centre  value directly is atleast $O(h^2)$ or second order accurate. But that would violate the conservation property of the scheme since $k_{i+1/2}^+ \neq k_{i+1/2}^-$. But we can  use linear interpolation  with $k_{i}, \; k_{i+1}$  to calculate $k_{i+1/2}$ and maintain $O(h^2)$ accuracy.

But in case of discontinuous $k$, I am still puzzled by order of accuracy of the  harmonic mean approximation for $k_{i+1/2}, \; k_{i-1/2}$, and how to  calculate $k_{i+1/2}, \; k_{i-1/2}$ at the boundary  cells.