# advection diffusion equation

Tags: advection-diffusion, advection, diffusion

Would you know what is the condition for stability for the advection-diffusion equation where we treat the diffusion part using Crank-Nicholson and the advection part using FCTS (forward in time centered in space)? I am applying von Neumann analysis but I am not sure about the final condition for stability. Do you know where I could find the proof for the stability of that scheme? Thank you

Comment: The relevant question is whether you are in the advection or diffusion dominated regime. Can you tell more about which effect is dominant in your case?

Comment: You could try a splitting scheme where you solve the diffusion term implicitly, and then solve the advection term explicitly

Comment: Click in the advection-diffusion tag in this site. There a few examples of how to do this within the Crank-Nicolson framework.

Comment: For example, this one, http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7399/how-to-discretize-the-advection-equation-using-the-crank-nicolson-method/