# Crank-Nicholson scheme for transport equation

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, hyperbolic-pde

This is my attempt to find the approximate solution of the folowing transport equation $$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\partial_{t} u+\partial_{x} u= (x^2-x)t+x^3/3-x^2/2, & t \in(0,0.4), x \in(0,1) \\
u(0, x)=2, & x \in(0, 1) \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0 & t \in(0,0.4), x=0\quad or \quad1 
\end{array}\right.$$
by using the following Crank-Nicholson scheme $$U_{i}^{j+1}+ \frac{k}{4h}({U_{i+1}^{j+1}-U_{i-1}^{j+1})=U_{i}^{j}- \frac{k}{4h}(U_{i+1}^{j}-U_{i-1}^{j}})+\frac{k}{2}\left[f_{i}^{j+1}+f_{i}^{j}\right]$$ it can work but it's too far from the exact solution $$u(t,x)=(x^3/3 -x^2/2)t + 2$$ I tried to found why but it turned out to be very difficult.

```
%% Left-hand side A*U

A=diag(-cte/4*ones(N-2,1),0)+diag(ones(N-3,1),1)+diag(cte/4*ones(N-4,1),2);
A = A([1:N-4],:);
A = sparse(A);

%% Fill in the initial condition 

for i=1:N-2
    uCN1(i)= g(a+(i+1)*h);  
end

uCN11= [uCN1(1); uCN1 ; uCN1(N-2)];  % Neumann boundary

uCN2=uCN1;
uCN22=uCN11;

%% uCN2
F=zeros(N-4,1);


%% Left-hand side C*U+F
C=diag(cte/4*ones(N-2,1),0)+diag(ones(N-3,1),1)+diag(-cte/4*ones(N-4,1),2);
C = C([1:N-4],:);
C = sparse(C);

for j=1:M-1

    for i=1:N-4
        F(i)=k*(f(S(i+2),T(j))+f(S(i+2),T(j+1)))/2;
    end

    F1=F;

    B1=C*uCN2+F1;  % Rght-hand side 

    % Solve for linear equation
    uCN2=A\B1;

    uCN22= [uCN2(1); uCN2 ; uCN2(N-2)];

    uCN=uCN2;


    uCN=uCN22;   % approximate solution
    plot(S,uCN,'c');
    R=j*k;
    title([' U at at T=' num2str(R)])
    pause(k)
end
```

**EDIT**

for the exact solution, I wrote this code:

```
for i=1:N
uEX(i)=(S(i)^3/3 -S(i)^2/2)*(0.4) +2; % I forgot +2
end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the plots of the numerical solution and the exact solution?

Comment: This now meets all the points I mentioned on the SO post, even without pictures (but pictures, moderately sized, are always nice).

Comment: I see a discrepancy between the initial condition $u(0,x)=2$ and the solution formula giving $u(0,x)=0$. If you add the constant to get $u(t,x)=2+t(x^3/3-x^2/2)$, this problem would vanish. Is this the difference you observe?

Comment: Thank you again, things always become nicer with your directions :))), sorry it was my mistake, I didn't add two in the expression of the exact solution

Comment: The pictures really added information. It is not that you get a different solution, but that the numerical solution process diverges completely.

Comment: you're right, do you know the reason??

Comment: Could you comment on your design decisions for the space discretization? As I see it from your initialization, $x=0$ corresponds to $a+2h$? And $x=1$ to $a+(N-1)h$? And these boundary elements correspond as per the construction of `F` to `S(3)` and `S(N-2)`? Or is that meant to be `S=a+[1:N]*h` so that the boundaries correspond to the virtual elements `S(0)` and `S(N+1)` and `h=1/(N+1)`?

Comment: But then I still do not understand your treatment of the boundaries, omitting to get the initial condition on $x_0,x_1$ and $x_N,x_{N+1}$? What is the reconstruction of these values from a given state vector? Did you convert this from a language with index-$0$-based arrays?

Comment: here is my discretization: `a=0;
b=1; 
h=0.01;
S=a:h:b;
N=size(S,2); 

c=0; 
d=0.4;
k=CFL*h;
T=c:k:d;
M=size(T,2);
` My idea is sine we have a Neumann boundary, $U_{2}^{j}=U_{1}^{j}$ and  $U_{N}^{j}=U_{N-1}^{j}$ for every j. I think that the problem is that I didn't include the boundary condition in the system, and I let the calculation of $U_{1}^{j}$ and $U_{N}^{j}$ after the I got the $U_{2}^{j}$ and $U_{N-1}^{j}$ from the inversion of the matrix $A$, and in this case the matrix $A$ won't be tridiagonal.

Comment: But why if the matrix $A$ isn't tridiagonal. I can't get the vector $U_{2}^{j},U_{3}^{j},..... ,U_{N-1}^{j}$

Comment: It defeats somewhat the purpose if you have an order 2 method but only implement the boundary conditions with order 1. This reduces the order of the method to 1 in space direction, to $O(h+k^2)$, but this is no reason for the observed divergence. With those explanations I'll look again at your code if I find some error there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the implementation of the boundary conditions. Apart from that you seem to not compute existing variables efficiently.

If I understand your initialization right, then $x_2=a+2h$ to $x_{N-1}=a+(N-1)h$ is the middle segment of the space discretization, so that $x_0=a=0$ implies $x_{N+1}=b=1$ and $h=\frac1{N+1}$. Shifting to index-one based arrays means that the state vector in space direction is `U(1:N+2)`.

### Analysis of your first order implementation

Your setup is that `S=a:h:b` and `N=lenght(S)`. The Neumann boundary conditions are implemented as $u(t,x_0)=u(t,x_1)$ and $u(t,x_{N-1})=u(t,x_{N-2})$. Then the state vector at time $t_j$ is $u^j_i=u(t_j,x_i)$, $i=1,...,N-2$, the initialization would have to be

```
U(1,:) = g(S(2:N-1));
```

(or via loop, use `S(i+1)` for the `x` value). In the C-N equation, the difference part on the right side acts on

```
[ U(j,1) U(j,:) U(j,N-2) ]
```

either via matrix multiplication or more simply due to the Toeplitz structure, via convolution. The function part can likewise constructed from the vectorized evaluations `f(T(j),S(2:N-1))`. (One might think about introducing `Si=S(2:N-1)` for the inner part of this array). Then the system for the left side is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1-α&α\\
-α&1&α\\
&\ddots&&\ddots\\
&&-α&1&α\\
&&&-α&1+α\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u^{j+1}_1\\u^{j+1}_2\\\vdots\\u^{j+1}_{N-3}\\u^{j+1}_{N-2}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
r_1\\r_2\\\vdots\\r_{N-3}\\r_{N-2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This matrix has dimension $N-2$, I do not understand how you can reduce it to size $N-4$ without accounting for the first and last row and their corresponding equations. You compute something for the inside of the inside, and have it only loosely connected to the boundary.

### Second order implementation

I prefer the convention where a subdivision has $N$ segments and thus $N+1$ node/sampling points $x_i=S(i+1)$.

```
S = linspace(a,b,N+1); h=S(2)-S(1);
```

The easiest way to implement the boundary conditions to second order is to use ghost cells. This means that one observes $u(t,-h)\simeq u(t,+h)$ and the same at the other boundary. In the implementation this means that the extended array standing for the extended node sequence $x_{-1},x_0,...,x_{N},x_{N+1}$ or (virtually) `S(0:N+2)` should be

```
[ U(2)  U  U(N) ]
```

The difference operator acting on this array could be realized as

```
conv ([ U(2)  U  U(N) ], [ -alf, 1, alf ], shape="valid")
```

as convolution applies the second factor in reversed order. `shape="valid"` removes the outer two elements on each side and thus restores the shape of `U` in the result.

To solve for the next step the system to be solved, using $u^j_1-u^j_{-1}=0$ and $u^j_{N+1}-u^j_{N-1}=0$, is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
-α&1&α\\
&\ddots&&\ddots\\
&&-α&1&α\\
&&&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_0\\u_1\\\vdots\\u_{N-1}\\u_{N}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
r_0\\r_1\\\vdots\\r_{N-1}\\r_{N}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $r_i$ is the right side of the C-N equation, that is, everything not depending on the $u^{j+1}_i$.

This can be shortened by reading off $u_0=r_0$ and $u_{N}=r_{N}$,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&α\\
-α&1&α\\
&\ddots&&\ddots\\
&&-α&1&α\\
&&&-α&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_{N-2}\\u_{N-1}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
r_1\\r_2\\\vdots\\r_{N-2}\\r_{N-1}
\end{bmatrix}
+α
\begin{bmatrix}
r_0\\ \\\vdots\\ \\-r_{N}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

In GNU octave the following works

```
function scicomp34793_crank_nicholson_4_transport
  clear all; clf;
  N = 10;
  M = 20;
  S = linspace(0,1,N+1)
  h = S(2)-S(1);
  T = linspace(0, 0.4, M+1)
  k = T(2)-T(1);

  v = 1;
  f=@(t,x) (x.^2-x).*t+x.^3/3-x.^2/2;
  g=@(x) 2+0*x;

  ref=@(t,x) 2+t.*(x.^3/3-x.^2/2);

  alf = v*k/(4*h);

  U(1,:) = g(S);

  C = spdiags([ -alf*ones(N-1,1), ones(N-1,1), alf*ones(N-1,1)], [-1,0,1], N-1,N-1);

  for j=1:M
    Ujdiff = conv([U(j,2)  U(j,:)  U(j,N)],[-alf,1,alf], shape="valid");
    R = 0.5*k*(f(T(j),S)+f(T(j+1),S)) + Ujdiff;
    R(2)  += alf*R(1);
    R(N) -= alf*R(N+1);
    U(j+1,:) = [ R(1) R(2:N)/C' R(N+1) ];
  end%for
  X = linspace(0,1,301);
  for j=1:M+1
    plot(X,ref(T(j),X),'b', 'LineWidth',6);
    ylim([1.9,2.03]);
    hold on;
    plot(S,U(j,:),'-oy', 'LineWidth',2);

    title([' U at at T=' num2str(T(j))])
    hold off;
    pause(k*20)
  end%for

end%function
```

[image: numerical solution over reference solution]

*numerical solution over reference solution*

Comment: See related answer with python implementation https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/7423/3691