# Stability of Crank-Nicholson for advection diffusion equation for spatial discretization other than finite differences second-order centered

Tags: finite-difference, time-integration, crank-nicolson

Crank Nicholson is a time discretization method (see 4th equation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method)). From what I see around, you can use different space discretization, such as Finite elements. But for the linear advection-diffusion equation, I see on books the von Neumann stability proof only when second-order centered spatial finite differences are used for both first and second-order derivatives (see e.g. [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5402/is-crank-nicolson-a-stable-discretization-scheme-for-reaction-diffusion-advectio)). My questions are:

1. If I use upwind, first or higher-order, higher-order centered differences, or finite elements, is the scheme always unconditionally stable for the linear advection-diffusion equation? Any reference?
2. Does the unconditional stability of Crank Nicholson also hold for only advection or only diffusion, and for any physical Peclet number?

Comment: Does this help you out? https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5402/3691

Comment: That is the one I linked. It only uses centered finite difference second order. No answer to my questions (1) and (2)

Comment: Oh missed the link one first read

Comment: Linear stability of the Crank-Nicolson scheme (the time integration scheme) is ensured if, for the system of ODE $y'=f(y)$ ($y$ being your discrete variables and $f$ the discrete operator representing convection diffusion and others, involving the spatial schemes of any order you like) the eigenvalues of the Jacobian $\frac{df}{dy}$ all have their real parts lower than or equal to zero, i.e. if they lie within the stability domain of the temporal scheme. So computing the eigenvalues of $f$ (they may vary in time if $f$ is non-linear) will give you a good overview of the numerical stability.

Comment: Mmm is that a result stemming from applying von Neumann stability analysis? any reference? Without having to do the math for each scheme (re-inventing the wheel) is there in any book a table with the list of common spatial discretization schemes for which Crank Nicholson is stable? Also: what about my question 2? Is there a general result that says: if the scheme for advection-diffusion is stable, then the same scheme is stable for the diffusion equation and the advection equation separately, whichever the Peclet number?